# How to save the QPixmap of a label which consist of one more label above it which has a Qpixmap

Tags: qt, qt5, qlabel, qpixmap

I have inherited the `QLabel` to create my own class of `QLabel`, The code is below:

```
class myLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myLabel(QWidget *parent=nullptr): QLabel(parent){ setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);}
    QLabel insideLabel;

};
```

As you can see, My class has one `QLabel` member inside.
Now, What I have done is that I created the object of my class and assign a image to it using `setPixmap()` and also assign a image to my `QLabel` member inside my class. The code is below:

```
    QFile file("file.png");
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //Creatig instance of my QLabel class and setting one image to it.
    myLabel *label=new myLabel(this);
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap("someImagePath"));
    
    //Assining image to my class QLabel member.
    label->insideLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap("someImagePath"));
    
    //saving file.
    label->pixmap()->save("imageName","png",-1);
```

So when I save the image it only save the image of my `QLabel` class object `QPixmap` instead of saving both of my label image as the `insideLabel` is present above the my label class object as it is it's member. How can i save both images of my labels as one image.

Comment: It is a little hard for me to understand what you are saying, please attach some code showing what you have.

Comment: actually i have one ```QLabel``` which contains a image and a another ```QLabel``` above the first label which also contains the image, Actually I want to save the image of both ```QLabel``` as one image, but qt saves only the image of one ```QLabel```. Hope you understand, wait let me modify my question to explain it briefly.

Comment: @VinayKumar please provide a [mre]

Comment: you should  definitely provide some code, as far as I know QLabel doesn't have any method nor concept of saving.

Comment: I have provided, you can check and please help me if there is anyway to save both the ```QLabels``` images as one.

Comment: The way you think about it is not possible. For me it sounds like a XY problem. Please share your actual goal, i.e. what do you want to achieve - do you want two separate files, or the images should be superimposed and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saved the needed portion of my `Widget` window as image, below is my code

```
    label=new myLabel(this);
    label->setGeometry(50,50,300,300);

    label->setPixmap(QPixmap("/home/vinay/Pictures/exp.png").scaled(label->width(),label->height()));
    label->insideLabel=new QLabel(this);
    label->insideLabel->setGeometry(50,50,50,50);
    label->insideLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap("/home/vinay/Pictures/exp2.png"));
    label->insideLabel->setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);
    label->insideLabel->setLineWidth(3);
    //Assining image to my class QLabel member.

    //saving file.
    label->pixmap()->save("imageName","png",-1);
    //ui->myWidget->grab().save("image.png");
    QRect r(50,50,300,300);
    Widget::grab(r).save("image.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not trying to save a QLabel, you are trying to save the pixmap property of a QLabel, those are two very different things.
A QLabel is a widget that can be rendered on a paint device. You should read the documentation about the QWidget subsystem:
[Qt Widgets module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html)

I see some problems with your code, the inside widget has no parent, and in your case I think that is a problem, but explaining that is beyond your question.

If what you want is to render the widget into an image file, you could do something like this:

```
 QPixmap pixmap(Widget->size());
 Widget->render(&pixmap);
 pixmap.save("widget_render_file.png");
```

If you want to compose an image you can directly draw on a painter attached to a pixmap like this:

```
 QPixmap pixmap(100,100);
 QPainter painter(pixmap);
 painter.setPen (...);
 painter.drawPixmap (...);
 painter.end();
 pixmap.save(...);
```

You should also check documentation on QPainter and QPixmap, there's a lot of useful drawing/painting functions.

Comment: Thanks it works, actually i wanted to compose the image present in ```insideLabel``` into the label object I created by ```myLabel``` class, but there is one problem in your code, THe resolution of the image is very bad as it is being painter so I have written the same logic with some other functions, you can check my answer below.